# Plotly.js - Hover label of multiple traces overlaps with xaxis hover label

Tags: javascript, plotly.js

I'm facing an issue where the hover label of multiple traces overlaps with the x-axis's hover label when all the trace values are close to 0.

In the example below, you can see the overlap when you mouseover `x=1000`

```js
const data = []
const x = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000];
data.push({
  x: x,
  y: [100, 105, 132, 150, 130, 103, 2, 200, 301, 1],

});

data.push({
  x: x,
  y: [200, 205, 232, 250, 230, 193, 1, 100, 201, 0],
})

data.push({
  x: x,
  y: [0, 205, 232, 250, 230, 193, 10, 100, 0, 0],
})

const layout = {
  height: 350,
  xaxis: {
    // tickformat: ',.2r',
  },
  hoverlabel: {
    font: {
      family: 'Helvetica Neue',
      size: 11,
    }
  }
}

Plotly.plot('graph', data, layout);
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Plotly.js -->
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="graph"></div>
</body>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RBpQPg

Any workarounds would be appreciated. For example, would it be possible to combine all the hover labels into 1 label somehow?

Comment: Set `hovermode:'closest'` in graph layout.It's showing only closest point info.

Comment: I have considered that but I would like to show all the related data values as well. Also thought about increasing yaxis in negative direction as well as playing around with `tickformat` to modify the xaxis tick but they aren't particularly good solutions.